java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running `uname` command
I am following this to use pdal in my Java program.
I have added following dependencies in my pom:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.pdal</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdal-native</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.pdal</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdal_3</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.pdal</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdal-scala_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>


Code is:
Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline(json, LogLevel.Info()); //error on this line
pipeline.execute();

But this fails with:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running uname command

I am not sure of origin of 'uname'. It's not part of my pipeline json.
What am I missing?
Edit:
Here is the stacktrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running `uname` command
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at com.github.sbt.jni.syntax.NativeLoader$.liftedTree1$1(NativeLoader.scala:21) ~[sbt-jni-core_3-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.github.sbt.jni.syntax.NativeLoader$.loadPackaged$1(NativeLoader.scala:22) ~[sbt-jni-core_3-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.github.sbt.jni.syntax.NativeLoader$.load$1(NativeLoader.scala:56) ~[sbt-jni-core_3-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.github.sbt.jni.syntax.NativeLoader$.load(NativeLoader.scala:59) ~[sbt-jni-core_3-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.github.sbt.jni.syntax.NativeLoader.<init>(NativeLoader.scala:6) ~[sbt-jni-core_3-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at io.pdal.Pipeline$.<init>(Pipeline.scala:50) ~[pdal_3-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at io.pdal.Pipeline$.<clinit>(Pipeline.scala:50) ~[pdal_3-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at io.pdal.Pipeline.<init>(Pipeline.scala:30) ~[pdal_3-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at io.pdal.Pipeline.<init>(Pipeline.scala:33) ~[pdal_3-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at com.lidarapidemo.lidarprocessing.LidarProcessor.streamPointCloudPostgis(LidarProcessor.java:100) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.lidarapidemo.controllers.LidarController.lambda$pointsInBoundingBox$0(LidarController.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startCallableProcessing$4(WebAsyncManager.java:348) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2024-08-13T12:15:25.380+05:30 ERROR 2384 --- [lidarapidemo] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Async processing failed: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running `uname` command
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at com.github.sbt.jni.syntax.NativeLoader$.liftedTree1$1(NativeLoader.scala:21) ~[sbt-jni-core_3-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.github.sbt.jni.syntax.NativeLoader$.loadPackaged$1(NativeLoader.scala:22) ~[sbt-jni-core_3-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.github.sbt.jni.syntax.NativeLoader$.load$1(NativeLoader.scala:56) ~[sbt-jni-core_3-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.github.sbt.jni.syntax.NativeLoader$.load(NativeLoader.scala:59) ~[sbt-jni-core_3-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.github.sbt.jni.syntax.NativeLoader.<init>(NativeLoader.scala:6) ~[sbt-jni-core_3-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at io.pdal.Pipeline$.<init>(Pipeline.scala:50) ~[pdal_3-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at io.pdal.Pipeline$.<clinit>(Pipeline.scala:50) ~[pdal_3-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at io.pdal.Pipeline.<init>(Pipeline.scala:30) ~[pdal_3-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at io.pdal.Pipeline.<init>(Pipeline.scala:33) ~[pdal_3-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at com.lidarapidemo.lidarprocessing.LidarProcessor.streamPointCloudPostgis(LidarProcessor.java:100) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.lidarapidemo.controllers.LidarController.lambda$pointsInBoundingBox$0(LidarController.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startCallableProcessing$4(WebAsyncManager.java:348) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]


Please provide the full exception stacktrace, and a [mre].

What's the operating system of your development machine/that machine you run the program on?

Stacktrace added. @tquadrat, its windows 11.

Looks like you might have woven in routines for the wrong operating system ( something Unix based)

On (at least) Linux, the uname command prints system information.  And the README for sbt-jni mentions that uname is a dependency.  So my guess is that you are trying to run pdal on an OS that is not supported.

Which is clearly documented: "Native binaries are prebuilt for Linux and MacOS and delivered in a jar", and a bit later "Dependency contains bindings for x86_64-darwin and x86_64-linux, other versions are not supported yet."

To summarize the comments: the library that you are using is not feasible for the operating system you run the program on.
uname is a program that exists on Unix (therefore also on Linux and MacOS), but not on Windows.
So running your program on Windows is expected to fail.
